# lua string split - how to split a string and get a substring starting from capital letter

Tags: lua, split

I have come across functions that split a string in lua ut my requirement is to split a string when it starts with a lowercase  letter, If it does,in my case the string is bound to have a part of string starting with capital letter like :

mdmMSH

in this case i would like to split while it starts at M and add MSH to a table.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab everything after the first uppercase letter in the string:

<strike>`sub = s:match('[A-Z].*')`</strike>

Per Egor's comment:

`sub = s:match'%u.*'`

Comment: `sub = s:match'%u.*'`